# check checkbox to move li from one list to another and uncheck to bring back to original position

Tags: jquery

As i am trying to move li between two list on check the checkbox and viceversa
some how manage to move from first list on check to second list, but stuck with moving back the li if i uncheck the checkbox

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B4XhH/6/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {    
var i=$('input:checkbox').index($(this));
if(confirm("Are you sure to move ? ")){
    $( '#wizard1 li:eq('+i+')' ).insertAfter( '#wizard2 li:last' );
}else{
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
         alert("gdfg");
         $(':checkbox').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
         //$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
     }
}
```

});

Comment: When moving an item back to the left, should it go at the bottom of the list or back in its original position? BTW, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: item should go to original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    var 
        $this = $(this),
        i = $this.closest('li').index(), //get the index of its parent li
        $target = $('#wizard2'); //default set the target as wizard2

    if (confirm("Are you sure to move ? ")) {
        if (!this.checked) {  //if unchecked
            $target = $('#wizard1'); //set the target as wizard1
        } else {
            $this.data('idx', i); //set the index in data api
        }

        var $targetLi = $target.find('li:eq(' + $this.data('idx') + ')'); //get the target li to see if this has the item li with index
        if ($targetLi.length) {  //if yes the append this item before that
            $targetLi.before($this.closest('li'));
        } else { //else append it to the ul
            $target.append($this.closest('li'));
        }
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsyWT/)**

Comment: Thanks a ton Exactly what I want

Comment: @user2234768 - you said if you uncheck the item on the right then it should appear in its original position. This doesn't do that.

Comment: @j08691 yes on repeated shifting some of the item is moved to new location

Comment: @user2234768 aah i see , check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xtGYx/ i am sure its not perfect.